# How do I make a labelled line chart?

Tags: visualization

suppose I want to track the ratings of seasons of a TV show. so there are three columns of data-season number, year, and ratings. I want the year and ratings on the axes and season number as labels on the points. how can this be achieved considering visualization tools only take in values for X and Y axes?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at matplotlib's [annotate](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432557/matplotlib-scatter-plot-with-different-text-at-each-data-point/14434334) are some examples. I believe it works well with seaborn too.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the tv show ratings of a season changes as time passes.
If you are using a library called **Pandas** there is a function called ***groupby***, which helps you to group certain columns of a dataframe and form a new dataframe.

To import pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

Groupby syntax

```
New_dataframe=old.groupby("Year")["Season Number"].function_you_want_to_use()
New_dataframe.plot(kind="bar",stacked="True")
```

If stacked is true the bars will will be on top of one another.

[image: This image is just an example from another dataset]

I don't have your exact data. So consider
*the x axis as year*
*the y axis as ratings*
*labels as season number(example S1-blue, S2-orange, S3-green)*